# What means __NSSingleObjectArrayI in Objective C? when I try to read a Json

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsarray

I have this code Json format:

```
{
    "weather": [{
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
    }],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 285.514
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1485792967,
    "id": 1907296
}
```

And I want to retrive icon string (01n)

And use this code:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *cityImageName;

self.cityImageName = [[dataJson valueForKey:@"weather"] valueForKey:@"icon"];
```

And later when I check the variable print:

```
<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x604000009890>(
01n
)
```

**Finally how can I get the string directly?** not like a `__NSSingleObjectArrayI`

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Comment: While the two answers are correct and explain what went wrong (`valueForKey:`), to answer your question, it's an internal class saying: "NSArray" "Immutable" (for the "I" at the end, to oppose to Mutable version, but that's implicit with "NSArray" vs "NSMutableArray") and optimized for having only One object ("SingleObject" part).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You got caught in the *Key-Value Coding Trap*.

`valueForKey` has a special behavior. Applied to an array it returns always an array of **all** values for the given key.

Never use `valueForKey` unless you intend to use KVC. The recommended syntax is `objectForKey` or  – preferable – key subscription and in case of the array index subscription.

In this case you want to get the value for key `icon` of the first item in the array for key `weather`.

```
self.cityImageName = dataJson[@"weather"][0][@"icon"];
```

---

However I would add a check if the array is not empty to avoid an out-of-range exception

```
NSArray *weather = dataJson[@"weather"];
if (weather && weather.count > 0) {
    self.cityImageName = weather[0][@"icon"];
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Now I understand how can I work with this situations.

Comment: I'm not able to get value through this

Answer (score 5):

`__NSSingleObjectArrayI` is one of the implementations of the `NSArray` [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html). It's not really important to this question other than knowing that it's an array.

The reason you're getting an array (of one element) instead of a string is because the JSON you're working with contains an array with one dictionary inside of it:

```
"weather": [{
    "description": "clear sky",
    "icon": "01n"
}],
```

**Note:** the square brackets surrounding the curly brackets.

So, when you call `[dataJson valueForKey:@"weather"]` you get back the object that represent this part of the JSON:

```
[ { "description": "clear sky", "icon": "01n" } ]
```

Which is in this case has been decoded as an `NSArray` containing one `NSDictionary` with two keys.

When you then call [`valueForKey:` on that array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1412219-valueforkey) it

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using `key` on each of the array's objects.

In other words, because `[dataJson valueForKey:@"weather"]` is an array of one dictionary, `[[dataJson valueForKey:@"weather"] valueForKey:@"icon"]` is an array of only the value for the `"icon"` key in that dictionary.

If the JSON you're working with always has this format, then you can get the [`firstObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1412852-firstobject?language=objc) from the array to get a hold of the first string (or `nil` if the array was empty).